# Value attribute not showing strings in function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When calling onClick on a Material-UI MenuItem and the value attribute is a string, the event function sees the value as zero.

If I add a value="sometext" to other elements like a button this works fine.  I'm still new to this but it seems like the string value should show.

What am I doing wrong?

```
handleClose(e) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget)
  console.log(e.currentTarget.value)
}

...

return (
  <Menu>
    <MenuItem value={1} onClick={this.handleClose}>One</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value='A' onClick={this.handleClose}>Two</MenuItem>
  </Menu>
);
```

In this example, if you click the first menu item, as expected the console output is:

```
<li ... value="1">...</li>
1
```

But the second menu item I'm expecting an 'A' but it returns:

```
<li ... value="A">...<li>
0
```

I tried using a string variable, using target instead of currentTarget. I can use id="A" instead of the value attribute and that works but I'd like to understand why this is happening.

Comment: What do you want to use this value for?

Comment: I'm learning JavaScript + React. So testing various ways of passing values. This was just a strange case that didn't seem to make sense. My tutorials listed value="something" as one way to pass data.

Comment: Yes, the syntax `prop="value"` is a valid way to pass a string as a prop value. I suggest you find a different prop or different component to test this with since the `value` prop of `MenuItem` is required to be a number and isn't useful anyway. For example `TextField` has a `label` prop that allows a string and is much more meaningful to see the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**li value attribute must be a number.**

0 is probably the default value, so when you set it to 'A', it gets the default value.

---

Just as a side note:

According to [li docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li), li value attribute has no meaning in unordered list (material-ui Menu uses < ul > under the hood- which is unordered list).

> ***value***
>
> This integer attribute indicates the current ordinal value of the list
> item as defined by the  element. The only allowed value for this
> attribute is a number, even if the list is displayed with Roman
> numerals or letters. List items that follow this one continue
> numbering from the value set. The value attribute has no meaning for
> unordered lists (< ul >) or for menus (< menu >).

Comment: I never thought to look at the li documentation. Thank you.

Comment: @chris358 Note that the [docuementation for `MenuItem`](https://material-ui.com/api/menu-item/) doesn't list `value` as an accepted prop anyway. This is a clue that you shouldn't use it.